# Decision boundary of an neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, machine-learning-model, binary-classification

[image]

Starting with a).

For the first unit: 0 * x1 + 1 * x2 + 1 > 0 (0, because the threshold is 0) which is the same as x2+1 > 0.

For the second unit: x1 * 1 + x2 * 0 + 1 > 0 (0, because the threshold is 0) which is the same as x1 + 1 > 0.

For the third unit: x1 * 1 + x2 * 1 + 1 > -1 (-1, because the threshold is -1. I might have misunderstood this since the assignment states "Circles indicate threshold units with threshold at zero...") which is the same as x1 + x2 > -2.

I then draw those lines. Is it correct so far? I can't however figure out how to solve b) How do I take the bias on the output node into account?

This is the given solution (but I don't understand how they got it):

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: I think you mixed intercept and threshold. The threshold is set to zero (read the text). The intercept is 1 * 0.0 for the first two nodes and 1 * (-1.0) for third one. This leads to different inequalities.

Comment: By the way: this looks like you are asking to do your homework. I know such kind of networks mainly from text books and for educational purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
I thought I was supposed to use this equation Σwjxj+bias=threshold for the nodes.  But I guess that isn't the case since I get the wrong answer if I just plugg in bias = 1 and threshold = 0, and I don't see anything about any 'intercept'.


What equation should I use? I feel a bit lost and I'm having a hard time figuring out how it all fits together. @Broele

Comment: Bias and intercept mean the same, here

Comment: Ok thanks! But what do the numbers next to the filled in circles stand for? I thought those were the bias. @Broele

Comment: The 1 next to the filled circle (you will never see another number, there) comes from an alternative view on the bias:
If you add another input dimension $x_3$ that is constantly set to 1, then the bias could be rewritten as $bias=w_3*x_3$. Then the inequality becomes $\sum w_jx_j > t$

Comment: Ok thank you that makes sense to me! So, for example, the input dimension x3 is equal to 1.0 for the third node and has weight -1.0? And that is the same as saying that the bias for the third node is -1.0? @Broele

Comment: exactly. 
Using $x_3=1$ is just a different way of expressing the same thing and you can use the weight as bias.

Answer (score 0):

What you assumed were thresholds appear to instead be weights on the edges from the passthrough nodes. At least, that makes the lines consistent with those in the plot.

I gave some hints to the same problem at [Draw(by hand) the decision boundary of an neural network](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/115421/55122) ; for the shading, note the output of each hidden neuron in each region and plug those into the output neuron.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But if those numbers I assumed were thresholds actually are weights on the edges from the passthrough nodes, then what are the '1.0's closer to the output node? I thought the '1.0's were the weights... @Ben

Comment: These are the weights for the output of the hidden layer when uses as input for the output layer.

Comment: @kim120 those are the weights for _those_ edges, giving the output as a linear combination of the (post-activation) output from the hidden neurons.